# How to disable reactjs warnings in figwheel ClojureScript?

Tags: reactjs, clojure, clojurescript, figwheel

I'd like to disable all warnings in my console, is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea to me. Warnings are there for a reason. Are you experiencing warnings that you cannot fix yourself?

Comment: @Magnar For development purpose I don't want to fix at the moment, I want to fix afterwards so I need them to get disabled.

Comment: Turn them off from dev tools?  Ignore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I do not recommend turning off the warnings, I believe you can get rid of the React warnings by using a production (minified) build of React.